# Can't change user security on folder - Business Objects XI 3.1

Tags: sap

I've got a single folder within the list of All Folders that I can't change any user permissions on.

I'm logged in as an admin and when I view security for the folder it says I have full rights to the folder yet i can't change anything on it or it's sub folders even though it clearly shows me as having rights to "Modify the rights users have to objects".

As a test I added a new sub-folder called Test which created ok but I'm not able to then delete the sub folder or change it's permissions either.

Interestingly we changed permissions on one sub-folder last week without issue but when I check that folder today I now can't update it.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not obvious from looking at my group membership it looks like some has set up a strange chain of groups and one of them had some explicit deny options set which I was inheriting.

With my account I seem unable to remove myself from the offending groups but I was able to create a fresh admin account to use!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an answer by now but (just in case).. if you select the offending folder, look at user security, highlight the groups that have access (in turn). What you get to one (or all) that have an assigned right of "do not delete" then remove; alternatively you may need to assign the Administer "full control" to allow you to delete.  The same will go for any subfolder you create as it will automatically carry the assigned security down to that level.  I tested by creating a sub folder I did not need, then looked at assigned rights and changed (as above) to allow me to delete.  Mo